# gvmd service not starting after postgresql replication - openvas

Tags: debian, postgresql, openvas, postgresql-replication, postgresql-cluster

I deployed two openvas servers on two distinct VMs (Debian 10) with postgresql version 11. I replicated the postgres 11 using  with hot standby configuration, the data is getting replicated but after the replication, gvmd service & gsad service goes down. On the other hand, ospd-openvas.service is up, but because of gvmd service is down, I am not able to log in.

In the log section, I am getting these errors:

**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpd3U.png)sql_exec_internal: SQL: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"**
**sqlv: sql_exec_internal failed**

systemctl status gvmd.service give me and error output of -

**gvmd.service: Can't open PID file /run/gvm/gvmd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory**

I tried to create an extension in postgresql of "uuid-ossp", but it postgres cannot create an extension in a read-only transaction.

transaction of postgresql cannot be set to read write mode because of the recovery file, and after removing recovery file from /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/recovery.conf  gvmd & gsad service starts normally.

I have attached screenshot recovery file used in postgresql replication.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpd3U.png)